# Worklight v6 Developers Reference Guide

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

There is a lovely Worklight Developer Reference Guide for v5 of Worklight (found here http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/wl_5_0_dev_ref.pdf) but I can't find it for V6...

Has anyone seen the update?

Cheers,
Susan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the same document, but for Worklight 6.0 is in existence.
Did you visit the IBM Worklight Information Center and Getting Started pages?

- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp
- http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/

Answer (score 0):

All of the previous Developer and Admin guide pdfs have been combined into the Worklight Information Center, per Idan's post. All of the same material is there, just re-organized, but if there is something you find missing, please post it and we can help.